# Java String split method split by 2 or more spaces

Tags: java, split, tokenize

How can I split a string by "2 or more spaces" only using the java split method

An example:

```
"cat dog    horse   elephant"
```

will be splitted into:

```
cat dog
horse
elephant
```

Thanks.

Comment: You've not at all looked at the `String#split` method? Made no effort to know how to have 2 or more of a character in a regex? Nothing?

Comment: SO is not a free coding service

Comment: `"cat dog    horse   elephant".split("\\s{2,}")` split use regex, so to match 2 or more spaces you can use `\s{2,}`

Comment: @F.Leone Those are "0 to infinity spaces" and "1 to infinity spaces", but it's a good start.

Comment: @AntoH Thats what i got in output https://screenshots.firefox.com/FPq9Ig70Z0ln4tHj/regex101.com .

How it should be? Thanks in advance

Comment: @F.Leone No, it shouldn't capture the space between "cat" and "dog", because there is only one space. OP is asking for minimum 2 spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the `String` using following `regex`

```
\\s{2,}
```

This will split the string by 2 or more spaces

```
String str = "cat dog    horse   elephant";
String[] parts = str.split("\\s{2,}");
```